ktor netty server POST serving timeouts
I have an api service like this:
fun Application.main()  {
        routing  {
            post( "/opendevice" )   {
                var   openResult = open_the_real_device()   // this take a long time (about 45 secs)
                call.response.status( HttpStatusCode.Created )
                call.responseText(openResult)
            }
        }
    }

I'm expecting to get 201 but instead I've got:
Unexpected code Response 500 Internal Server Error after 40 seconds
Apparently the Netty timeout and kill the coroutine
I already try to extend the timeouts during initialization:
myHttpServer = embeddedServer( Netty , port=8080, 
                               module=Application::main,
                               configure = {
                               responseWriteTimeoutSeconds = 120
                               requestReadTimeoutSeconds = 120 })
myHttpserver.start()

But it have no effects
I'm using ktor 2.3.12

I cannot reproduce the problem if, for illustrative purposes, the open_the_real_device function just suspends for 45 seconds using the delay function.

When I simulate open_real_device() like this: fun open_real_device() : String { Thread.sleep(45000); return "done" } it did not time out

But on the other hand, when I change responseWriteTimeoutSeconds = 10;                                requestReadTimeoutSeconds = 10; it still did not time out after 10 seconds. Why responseWriteTimeoutSeconds and requestReadTimeOutSeconds has no effects ?

Can you try to use the 3.0.0-beta-2 version? Some related issues have been fixed in Ktor 3.0.0.
